# Azure web job multiple connection strings

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Azure WebJob obtains connection string from web application (which runs the job) configuration parameter - AzureWebJobsStorage.
I need to monitor two queues in different storages using one WebJob.
Is it possible somehow to have multiple connection strings for a WebJob?

Comment: Can't you add multiple connection strings with different names and values?

Comment: AFAIK Azure WebJob uses the default connection string name "AzureWebJobsStorage" from parent application.

Comment: Do you have any code example where you use the connection string?

Comment: @henmer, are you familiar with webjobs at all?
WebJobs SDK takes in account AzureWebJobsStorage connection string from parent application. I cannot access it t WebJob, because WebJobs knows nothing about where it will be hosted.

Comment: @minuzZ // `AzureWebJobsStorage`'s just _default_ but not the only thing. you can do with multiple connection strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related to this post it is possible :

- [servicebus webjob different connection string for output or trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33126342/4167200)

In your case, you'd like to bind to differents storage accounts so your function can look like that:

```
public static void JobQueue1(
    [QueueTrigger("queueName1"),
    StorageAccount("storageAccount1ConnectionString")] string message)
{

}

public static void JobQueue2(
    [QueueTrigger("queueName2"),
    StorageAccount("storageAccount2ConnectionString")] string message)
{

}
```

You can also implement a custom INameResolver if you want to get the connectionstrings from the config :

```
public class ConfigNameResolver : INameResolver
{
    public string Resolve(string name)
    {
        string resolvedName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[name];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resolvedName))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot resolve " + name);
        }

        return resolvedName;
    }
}
```

to use it:

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.NameResolver = new ConfigNameResolver();
...
new JobHost(config).RunAndBlock();
```

And your new functions look like that:

```
public static void JobQueue1(
    [QueueTrigger("queueName1"),
    StorageAccount("%storageAccount2%")] string filename)
{

}

public static void JobQueue2(
    [QueueTrigger("queueName2"),
    StorageAccount("%storageAccount1%")] string filename)
{

}
```

- storageAccount1 and storageAccount2 are the connection string key in the `appSettings`